# 32х битный vermagic в 64х битном объектнике

Tags: gcc, kernel, кросс-компиляция

**Предыстория**: собрал в CYGWIN косс компилятор под линукс для 32х и 64х битных "эльфов". Проверил что результирующие файлы успешно отрабатывают в UBUNTU 32 и 64 соответственно - то бишь компиляторы справляются с задачей.

Захотелось мне собрать модуль ядра!!! Я запустил в линуксе Make с параметром **-v**, и все что он скармливает GCC я точно также скормил GCC который у меня на винде. Плюс стырил из линукса **__versions** секцию. И на 32битном кросе все собралось и модуль успешно стартовал на линуксе через **insmod**.

**Суть проблемы**: когда я то же самое проделал с 64битным кросс компилятором, он мне в VERMAGIC засунул строчку **4.8.0-22-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686**. И проблема именно в том что тут есть **686**. Изза нее при запуске модуля на линуксе мне ядро говорит **version magic '4.8.0-22-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 ' should be '4.8.0-22-generic SMP mod_unload modversions**. При этом когда я без MAKE через команды GCC проделываю то же самое на линуксе в собранном файле никакого 686 нет. В чем может быть беда. Команды я одни и те же скармливаю GCC на линуксе и на винде. Только один мне добавляет 686 а другой нет

Answer (score 1):

**Если будут ещё ненормальные вроде меня отвечаю:**

проблема была в том что при добавлении в кросс компилятор файлов от целевой ОС (в моем случае это ubuntu 4.8.1) я забыл поправить файл автоконфигурирования. В результате компилятор подхватывал этот файл и генерил мне точно то что там указано и для 32 и для 64. Так что просто подправив файл в соответствии с файлом на целевой платформе был получен рабочий модуль ядра